# lxml.etree XML parsing with HTML response content

Tags: python, lxml

For the following piece of XML, I want to extract child and subchild node values.

But when I am doing so with the following code, it is not giving me all the child nodes but the first only. My only objective is to put child & subchild nodes into a `csv` having column:

```
'RequestHeader', 'RequestBody', 'ResponseHeader', 'ResponseBody'
```

Here is my code:

```
reqRespXml = open(FILEPATH, 'rb').read()
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
root = etree.fromstring(reqRespXml, parser=parser)

for i, child in enumerate(root):
    for subchild in child:
        print(etree.tostring(
            subchild, pretty_print=True, method='html', encoding="UTF-8"))
```

The variable `FILEPATH` has the following XML as the input:

```
<root>
<child>
<RequestHeader>ABC</RequestHeader>
<RequestBody>DEF</RequestBody>
<ResponseHeader>GHI</ResponseHeader>
<ResponseBody>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>cccc</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/util.js"></script>
</head><body>

<center>
<table width="80%" class="border">
<tr BGCOLOR=#C3D9FF>
<td align="center" colspan="6">
<H1>ABC</H1>
<table width="100%" class=\"noborder\">
<tr BGCOLOR=#C3D9FF>
<td align="center" width="30%">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center" width="40%">Wxxxx</td>
<td align="center" width="30%" style="text-align: right" >
Guest user</html>
</ResponseBody>
</child>
<child>
<RequestHeader></RequestHeader>
<RequestBody></RequestBody>
<ResponseHeader></ResponseHeader>
<ResponseBody>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>aaaa</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/util.js"></script>
</head><body>

<center>
<table width="80%" class="border">
<tr BGCOLOR=#C3D9FF>
<td align="center" colspan="6">
<H1>XYZ</H1>
<table width="100%" class=\"noborder\">
<tr BGCOLOR=#C3D9FF>
<td align="center" width="30%">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center" width="40%">xxxx</td>
<td align="center" width="30%" style="text-align: right" >
Guest user</html>
</ResponseBody>
</child>
</root>
```